Gnome Wayland not starting after cold boot
I've been having an issue for a couple of weeks, ever since an apt upgrade not long ago.
Whenever I log in after a cold boot, launching Gnome on Wayland (my default setup) gets me stuck on a grey screen, like it never gets past GDM. I can login to Gnome on Xorg just fine, and if I then log out I can start a Wayland session just fine.
I have an Nvidia graphics card, I suspect it may be related to this issue; something tells me a service may be configured to start on Xorg but not on Wayland, and when closing the session the service would still be running.
Any help appreciated!
